# Проверка SSL сертификатов в js на django

Tags: javascript, python, django

Доброго времени суток изучаю Django пишу форму для заказа такси с сайта мне надо из файла js делать GET и POST запросы к серверу, когда делаю запрос получаю в ответ GET https://ip:port/common_api/1.0/ping net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID как обойти проверку сертификата ? Запрос в js делаю через XMLHttpRequest. В Python когда отправляю GET запросы ставлю verify=False есть ли тут такая возможность ? Вот сам запрос:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
send_sms.click('submit', function () {
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://ip:port/common_api/1.0/ping', true);
    xhr.send();
    console.log(xhr.responseText)
})
```

Comment: Добавить сертификат в доверенные в настройках браузера

Comment: не будет каждый клиент кто хочет заказать такси добавлять к себе эти сертификаты

Comment: Ну тогда приобретите настоящий сертификат и никакие проверки отключать станет не надо, что мешает?

Comment: Только надо будет ещё и домен приобрести. Сертификаты на ip не выдают (простым смертным)

Comment: Разработчики программного обеспечения забили на это дело и новые сертификаты не предоставляют

Comment: А неужели нету способа их программно игнорировать?

Comment: Нет. Смысл HTTPS именно в том, что бы его нельзя было игнорировать.

Comment: А есть возможность из js выполнить функцию из views и получить от неё данные ?